# GRUB Change EFI to BIOS legacy boot mode

Tags: grub2, uefi, bios

I need to change the boot mode of an UNIX system from EFI to BIOS. 
This system (Fedora Atomic Host) uses GRUB as a default bootloader.

I need to change the bootloader to BIOS, because I want to install TrustedGRUB2
in order to implemented hard disk encryption using a TPM. But I can't completely reinstall the system.

Are there any options to solve this?

Comment: The TPM and trusted boot is an EFI thing; you don't want to switch to BIOS booting.

Comment: @psusi TPM and (U)EFI are different things. A TPM is a separate crypto processor on the motherboard.

Comment: @JohanMyréen, yes, but using it requires UEFI.

Comment: @psusi It is not true that you can't use the TPM independently of UEFI. Some uses of the TPM may be coupled with UEFI, but that's not true in the general case.